# Scala: getting error as "Expression of type Unit doesn't confirm to expected type..."

Tags: scala, jersey-client

I am setting the connection timeout for [Client](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client/1.11/com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client.java#621) like

```
def newClient(host: String): Client = asyncHttpClient match {
    case true => {
        import org.sonatype.spice.jersey.client.ahc.AhcHttpClient
        AhcHttpClient.create()
    }
    case _ => {
        import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client
        val client: Client = Client.create()
        client.setConnectTimeout(5000)
        //Or client.setConnectTimeout(Int.box(5000))
    }
}
```

and getting the error message

> Expression of type Unit doesn't confirm to expected type Client

Could someone help to understand the problem and properly pass the integer value?

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suspect you have this code at the end of a method that's supposed to return a `Client`, but it'd be better if I could see the code, so I don't have to guess.

Comment: I updated the code, I think the return type after `client.setConnectTimeout(5000)` is not correct but not sure hoiw to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is declared to return a value of type `Client`. The return type of `client.setConnectionTimeout` is `Unit`, not `Client`, so you can't return that from your method. Instead you should return `client`:

```
def newClient(host: String): Client = asyncHttpClient match {
    case true => {
        import org.sonatype.spice.jersey.client.ahc.AhcHttpClient
        AhcHttpClient.create()
    }
    case _ => {
        import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client
        val client: Client = Client.create()
        client.setConnectTimeout(5000)
        client
    }
}
```